# Azure Logic App Outlook Connector has wrong Message ID

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-logic-apps

The Azure Logic App Outlook Connector provides several fields of the current mail, such as MessageID.

Now this MessageID doesn't match the id seen in the header details in Outlook or in the receiving email client.

So here's the MessageID found in Outlook Connector:

```
AAMkADdhZjg4ODViLTc1OGUtNGRjNC04ZDliLTIwZTg2YzNkZTMwOQBGAAAAAABheCsi2Dw6RL6VGEzI0_HnBwAcT26EfBI9QZDS3n-XAJGgAAAA789EAABtmqUPlGrSTqeUxgoZ3vaxAABn3JRvAAA=
```

and here's the id found in Outlook or the receiving email client:

```
<BL0PR210B46864401MB0900339BFCE05D5297C86@BL0PR2101MB0900.namprd21.prod.outlook.com>
```

Is there any way to related these two ids? We've already tried base64 encoding..

Comment: Looks like the MessageID is base64 encoded ???

Comment: We've already tried base64 encoding. Fortunately the email including the desired id can be retrieved with Microsoft Graph API (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADdhZjg4ODViL...) but hopefully there's an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Internet Message ID option

[image]